# How can add new plotBand to gauge type of highchart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have used the following [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rmgk1v6p/64/) gauge chart. I am looking for to add new plotBand at spesific range of (from ,to).

But, when i add new plotBand, by the followind command:

```
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                from: 0,
                to: 100,
                color: "#E0E0E0",
                thickness: "10%",
            });
```

the new added plotBand does not completely cover the old plotBand and the old one's border is visible!. How can hide completely the old one?
I must say that, using addPlotBand function is my only approach to add plotband.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused due to SVG artifacts. As a workaround, set the plotBands border width at 0.5 - 1.

```
  chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
    borderColor: "#E0E0E0",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    from: 0,
    to: 100,
    color: "#E0E0E0",
    thickness: "10%",
  });
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gzbsw80f/

Comment: Thanks. This solution pretty worked. but not absolutely covered again at small gauge size.

Comment: I checked this based on the following demo and seems to be working fine with increased border to 1px https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kcpb94y2/